# Search c# method name with javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

I know that you can search function names in javascript with:

```
arguments.callee.toString().match('/function ([^\(]+)/)')[1];"
```

But is is possible to search for C# method names with javascript?

Comment: You can call c# method using ajax. Why you don't use that?

Comment: @Thili77, didn't know about that, thank you

Comment: [Try](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8911c4/how-to-call-C-Sharp-methodfunction-using-jquery-ajax/) this

Answer (score 1):

It is completely impossible as C# is a server side scripting language, which means that the code is executed on the server, and therefore it cannot be accessed by JavaScript. You should use C# itself to approach your goal.

Comment: Not so; you could use node.js server-side to evaluate every character of a c# code file (using javascript).

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript to make a request to a C# server/application/function. Within that function, you can search for method names in your solution. Finally you return your results, and process them in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can call c# method easily using ajax, see below code,

In your server side ,

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Your_method()
{
    //something
}
```

In your client side ,

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'PageName.aspx/Your_method',
    data: '{ }',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Try this.